# Laravel 5 get user info from facebook

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-5

I'm trying to get an user id from Facebook with the Facebook PHP-sdk with Laravel 5. I did a lot of search on the errors I got, but none of the answers helped.

Set keys:

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('XXX' , 'XXX');
```

Redirect to Facebook:

```
public function getFacebook()
{
    $helper = new FacebookHandler(url('settings/set_facebook'));
    return Redirect::to($helper->getLoginUrl());
}
```

Get the info:

```
public function setFacebook()
{
    try{
        $session = new FacebookSession(\Session::get('state'));
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        dd($graphObject);
    } catch(Exception $e){
        dd(
            $e->getMessage(),
            $e->getCode(),
            $e
        );
    }
}
```

Code for Laravel sessions:

```
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class FacebookHandler extends FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
{
    protected function storeState($state)
    {
        Session::put('state', $state);
    }

    protected function loadState()
    {
        return $this->state = Session::get('state');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"Invalid OAuth access token."

190

FacebookAuthorizationException {#215 ▶}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Laravel Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite). It supports facebook, twitter, google+ and github.
and also easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing setFacebook() and update getFacebook() to this:

```
$helper = new FacebookHandler(url('settings/get_facebook'));

try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
    dd($e);
} catch( Exception $e ) {
    dd($e);
}

if (isset($session))
{
    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/me'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

    dd($user_profile);
} else {
    return Redirect::to($helper->getLoginUrl());
}
```

Of course you need to customize the error handling.